# coordinate transformation and tensor

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, tensors

A 2 dimensional Euclidean space is represented by two different coordinate systems: the Cartesian system $(x_1,x_2)$ and an alternative system $(\xi^1,\xi^2)$ where
$$x_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\xi^1+\xi^2)$$
$$x_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\xi^1-\xi^2)$$
A quantity $e(i,j)$ is defined such that in both coordinate systems

$$
e(1,1)=e(2,2)=0,$$
$$
e(1,2)=1$$

$$e(2,1)=-1$$

Do the quantities $e(i,j)$ represent the components of a tensor?

I am not sure how to start.  Can anyone help me plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that this quantity is a tensor we need to show that coordinate representation of the quantity is invariant under a change of coordinates.

The question stipulates that, for the vectors with coordinates $\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{c}y_1\\y_2\end{array}\right)$ in the cartesian system, the matrix representation of the quantity implies

$$
\left(x_1,\  x_2 \right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}y_1\\y_2\end{array}\right){}={}x_1y_2-x_2y_1\,.
$$
Note, also, that this form must also hold for the alternative coordinate system as well. That is, if the vectors have the alternative coordinates $\left(\begin{array}{c}\xi_1\\\xi_2\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{c}\zeta_1\\\zeta_2\end{array}\right)$, respectively, then we must also have
$$
\left(\xi_1,\  \xi_2 \right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}\zeta_1\\\zeta_2\end{array}\right){}={}\xi_1\zeta_2-\xi_2\zeta_1\,,
$$
for this to be a tensor. However, by direct substitution using the given change of coordinates transformation, we see that
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_1y_2-x_2y_1&{}={}&\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(\left(\xi_1+\xi_2\right)\left(\zeta_1-\zeta_2\right)-\left(\zeta_1+\zeta_2\right)\left(\xi_1-\xi_2\right)\bigg)\newline
&&\newline
&{}={}&\zeta_1\xi_2-\zeta_2\xi_1\newline
&&\newline
&{}\ne{}&\xi_1\zeta_2-\xi_2\zeta_1\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Therefore, the quantity is not a tensor!